# Luma and Chroma

Tags: video, colors, compression, hevc

Hi In a Particular YUV Sequence how to know whether Chroma Details are more OR Luma Details are more. Because sometimes Chroma PSNR gains are too good and Luma dropped. Does it mean Chroma Details are more...

Comment: What does it mean for details to be more? more what?

Comment: what i mean is if there is more of color information than brightness...then chroma PSNR will have more effect than Luma...is it true?

Comment: More effect on what? Human vision is more sensitive to luma then chroma. So you can not simply compare the PSNR of the channels.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't mean that chroma have more details than luma! Most likely you are using YCbCr 4:2:0 where the chroma part has been subsampled. The Cb-part contains 1/4 of the data (and the same for the Cb-part).

PSNR just compares the pixel-values in a specific position (i.e. average sum of squared difference) and since they have been subsampled, PSNR value will be higher since the similarities are greater.

For a full workthrough of MSE/PSNR etc. see http://www2.units.it/ramponi/teaching/DIP/materiale/mse_bovik09.pdf